# The winding number and index of curve

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

If $\gamma $ is a smooth closed curve in $\mathbb R^2-\{0\}$, I want to know whether the winding number of $\gamma $ about $0$, i.e., $\frac{1}{{2\pi i}}\int\limits_\gamma  {\frac{1}{z}} dz$ is equal to the index of $\gamma $ about $0$, that is, the degree of ${S^1} \to {S^1}$ through $t \to \frac{{\gamma (t)}}{{\left| {\gamma (t)} \right|}}$?

If so, it gives us a convenient way to calculate the index of curve. Is there any analogy in higher dimension?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the index of a curve around $0$ is equal to the winding number $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_\gamma \frac{dz}{z}$.  Note that this can also be written as a line integral: $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi}\oint_\gamma \frac{-y\,dx+x\,dy}{r^2}$, where $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

There are two simple generalizations of this formula to three dimensions.  First, if $S$ is any closed paramterized surface, then we can compute the index of $S$ around the origin using the surface integral
$$\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_S \frac{\textbf{r}\cdot\textbf{n}}{r^3}\;dA,
$$
where $\textbf{n}$ is the normal vector to the surface, $\textbf{r}$ is the vector $(x,y,z)$,  and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$.  This formula generalizes to $n$ dimensions, with $4\pi$ replaced by the $(n-1)$-dimensional area of the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $r^3$ denominator replaced by $r^n$.

The other generalization is the integral formula for the [linking number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_number) of two closed curves.  If $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$ are disjoint closed curves in $\mathbb{R}^3$, their linking number is given by the following double line integral:
$$
\frac{1}{4\pi}\oint_{\gamma_1}\oint_{\gamma_2} \frac{\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2}{\|\textbf{r}_1-\textbf{r}_2\|^3}\cdot(d\textbf{r}_1\times d\textbf{r}_2)
$$
In the case where one of the curves is the $z$-axis, this presumably simplifies to the line integral for winding number given above.

More broadly, the idea of computing topological invariants using integrals leads to [De Rham cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology).  Winding number is really a cohomology class on the punctured plane, and you are computing the value of this cohomology class on a closed curve by integrating a certain [differential form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_form) over the curve.  Using De Rham cohomology, this can be generalized to virtually any real-valued cohomology class on any [differentiable manifold](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_manifold).

Comment: +1 This is a great answer.  (And I didn't know that the linking number generalized the winding number in that way.  Very interesting.)