# Winding number in higher dimensions

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology, winding-number

I am searching for references about the generalization in higher dimensions of the winding number (or "engulfing number") of a (hyper)surface $S$ around a point $p$, especially the identity of :

- (a) the number of times the curve/surface/hypersurface winds around the point $p$ (that is, if I understand correctly, $\pi_{n-1}(\mathbb{R}^{n} - p) = \pi_{n-1}(S^{n-1})=\mathbb{Z}$)
- (b) the number of signed intersections or any ray from $p$ and the surface $S$
- (c) the flux through $S$ of the "electric" field of a point charge located in $p$

The identity of those numbers is intuitive, but I would like to know if it can be proved.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153116/what-is-the-winding-number/153146#153146) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/131752/the-winding-number-and-index-of-curve/131766#131766) are related (but provide no reference), and I have found some exercises about that in William Fulton's Algebraic Topology, but nothing where the different points of view (a), (b) and (c) are linked (even in two dimensions).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll follow an algebraic approach here, and make reference to Hatcher's "Algebraic Topology", available at http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html.

Given a map $f : S^{n-1} \to S^{n-1} \simeq R^n - p$, we can, as you say, measure its winding number as the homotopy class $[f] \in \pi_{n-1}(S^n-1) \cong \mathbb{Z}$, but we'll have to adapt this a bit for general hypersurfaces rather than spheres. We can compute the same number with the induced map $f_* : \pi_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \to \pi_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$, as this is a linear map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$, which is just multiplication by some integer. This integer is the same winding number, just from thinking through definitions. We could compute similarly in homology, with $f_* : H_{n-1}(S^{n-1}) \to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ again being multiplication by the very same winding number, by the Hurewicz theorem relating homotopy and homology groups (see Hatcher Sec. 4.2).

Homology is convenient, because a general (compact, oriented) $(n-1)$-manifold still has $H_{n-1}(M) \cong \mathbb{Z}$. So with an $(n-1)$-manifold $M$ and a map $f : M \to \mathbb{R}^n - p \simeq S^{n-1}$, the induced map $f_* : H_{n-1}(M) \to H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ is again a map $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$ (after a choice of generators, i.e. orientations), which is multiplication by an integer, which is our generalized winding number. We could use the induced map in cohomology equally well (by the Universal Coefficient Theorem, Hatcher thm. 3.2, or similar).

Note that we could also replace the target $S^{n-1}$ by a different $(n-1)$-manifold. In this generality, the number that we're computing is usually called the "degree" of the map $f$. These definitions appear in Hatcher, at the start of section 2.2 for spheres, and then in the exercises for more general manifolds.

For a "typical" point in the target $S^{n-1}$, the preimage consists of finitely many points in $M$. This amounts to intersecting $M \subset \mathbb{R}^n - p$ with a ray from $p$. Hatcher shows in Prop. 2.30 that the degree can be computed as a sum of signs associated to these points, and we can compute these signs from induced maps on local homology, which amounts to thinking about orientation. So we've bridged (a) and (b) from your question.

I'll be a bit brief on (c), but as we can compute degree through cohomology, we can in particular compute with differential forms by using De Rham cohomology. As I understand it, the electric field determines a dual $(n-1)$-form, which happens to generate $H_{dR}^{n-1}(\mathbb{R}-p)$. We pull this back along $f$ to the manifold $M$, and look at what multiple of the chosen generator (volume form) in $H_{dR}^{n-1}(M)$ it determines, which we compute by integrating. This computes the induced map $f^*$ on cohomology. I imagine that Guillemin and Pollack is a decent reference, though I don't have it on hand.

Comment: Thanks, it clarifies a number of things. If I understand correctly, to link preimages and the intersection with a ray, if I have a map $f : M \to N$ where $N$ is a surface is $\mathrm{R}^{n} - $, so $N \approx S^{n-1}$, and I define the projection $\pi$ from $N$ to the sphere $S^{n-1}$ with centre $p$ (which normalizes to $1$ the radial position wrt $p$), then the degree of $f : M \to N$ is the degree of $\pi \circ f : M \to S^{n-1}$. Is that correct ?

Comment: By the way, I don't fully understand the last part, but I will post a more specific question if needed so I accept you answer. Thanks !

Comment: Sounds like you basically have it right. In homology, we can treat $S^{n-1}$ and $\mathbb{R}^n - 0$ interchangeably, via the projection you describe. But the result about computing degree through a signed sum of preimage points is for manifolds of the same dimension (and, strictly, this is when we use the word "degree"). So to apply that result we should think about the preimage of a point in $S^{n-1}$ under $\pi \circ f$, but we can take that preimage in stages, first through $\pi$ to a ray in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then through f (which amounts to intersecting the ray with M).

Comment: @WilliamPerry Forgive me for a likely uninteresting question, but how would we show that for 'typical' points in the target $S^{n-1}$ the preimage consists of finitely many points?  In the smooth case this makes sense via a Sard's Theorem type argument I'd imagine but how would I show this to be generic in the continuous case?

Answer (score 1):

You want homology, or better yet, cohomology. Gauss's Law is based on (the vector field equivalent of the unique closed-but-not-exact $(n-1)$-form on $\mathbb R^n -\{0\}$. For (b), you want the Degree Theorem — see Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Could you kindly explain a little more (perhaps your answer is enough for a mathematician ... but I'm not one)  ? Do you have references about the link between the winding number and (co)homology ? In Guillemin and Pollack, a homotopy-invariant winding number is defined as an "intersection number", but I don't really see the relation with the intersection with a ray. Thanks anyway !